# Vuejs 3 API documentation

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm interested in having a deeper look into Vue.js v3 even before it's released. Is there an (WIP) API documentation somewhere? Like this one:

> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/

All I could find were some articles and semi-official publications. Tried this [repository](https://github.com/vuejs/vuejs.org), but there's no branch named *dev* or such.

i know it's still work in progress, but still, is there no in-house kept doc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Since July 2020 You can find the official docs of Vue 3 via this link **[v3.vuejs.org](https://v3.vuejs.org/)****

---

You could check the [composition api official doc](https://composition-api.vuejs.org/), this [article](https://vuedose.tips/tips/easily-switch-to-composition-api-in-vuejs-3) from [vuedose.tips](https://vuedose.tips), this [playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLJNLwTPak6dhC5HGSud_mR1Lchhr8mXeT) from *Vue mastery youtube channel* or [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8jOVi4fRSKo).

And a basic example that shows how that api looks :

```
<template>
  <button @click="increment">
    Count is: {{ state.count }}, double is: {{ state.double }}
  </button>
</template>

<script>
import { reactive, computed } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      count: 0,
      double: computed(() => state.count * 2)
    })

    function increment() {
      state.count++
    }

    return {
      state,
      increment
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a RFC going on here: https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/function-apis/active-rfcs/0000-function-api.md

You can also check Erik's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_LLUdzTIpBA) on youtube

Answer (score 2):

The Vue3 docs are ungoogleable and are at https://v3.vuejs.org/